# Proof of the formula for the number of Jordan blocks

Tags: jordan-algebras

here's what I need help with:
Let A$\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ be a Jordanizable matrix. Let n$_k(\lambda)$ be the number of J$_k$($\lambda$) blocks.
I'm trying to prove this formula:
n$_k$($\lambda$)=rank($(A-\lambda)^{k+1}$)+rank($(A-\lambda)^{k-1}$)-2 $\cdot$ rank($(A-\lambda)^k$)
for every 1$\leq$k

Comment: Can this be true? It would give the same value of $n_k(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda$. I suspect that the $A$'s should be $(A-\lambda)$s.

Comment: Apologies, youre correct and they fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have stated is not true in general, but it is true for $\lambda=0$.

To prove this we may assume that $A$ is already in Jordan form, since similar matrices have equal rank. Write $\rho(B)$ for the rank of $B$. Suppose that $\chi_A(X)=X^m g(X)$ where $g(0)\not=0$ and the degree of $g$ is $(n-m)$.

Then
$$
\rho(A^0)= (n-m)+ n_1(0)\cdot 1+n_2(0)\cdot 2 + n_3(0)\cdot 3+\dots
$$
and
$$
\rho(A^1)= (n-m)  +n_2(0)\cdot 1 + n_3(0)\cdot 2+\dots
$$
and
$$
\rho(A^2)= (n-m)   + n_3(0)\cdot 1+\dots.
$$

In general we have that

$$
\rho(A^s)=(n-m)+ \sum_{r=s}^{n} n_r(0)\cdot (r-s)
$$

From this last we can deduce the required
$$
n_k(0)=\rho(A^{k+1}) - 2\rho(A^k) +\rho(A^{k-1})
$$
at once.

The true result for general $\lambda$ is that

$$
n_k(\lambda)=\rho((A-\lambda)^{k+1}) - 2\rho((A-\lambda)^k) +\rho((A-\lambda)^{k-1}).
$$

Comment: Apologies, the formula was fixed because they added a fix to the practice page, thank you for your answer.